# Adjusting geom_point() and geom_line() separately

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a simple plot using ggplot. The problem is that the resulting plot adjusts only the linetypes but does not display the points. Here's a working example:

```
a <- matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=9)
a[,1] <- rnorm(9)
a[,2] <- runif(9)

colnames(a)<-c("first","second")


a <- melt(a,id.vars=1:1)
colnames(a)<-c("c", "variable", "value")
b <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i")
f <- cbind(b,a)
f$variable <- factor(f$variable, levels=c("first", "second"))
colnames(f) <- c("b","c","variable","value")

ggplot(f, aes(x=b, y=value, colour=variable, size=variable, linetype=variable, group=variable)) + geom_point() + geom_line()+scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue3","red3"))+scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,1))+scale_size_manual(values=c(0.3,0.3))+theme_bw()
```

My problem is that the lines are displayed but I would also like to have dots for the Y-values at each value of the X-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. First, if you need the same linetype for both lines (you set them to the same type with `scale_linetype_manual()`) then just don't use `linetype=variable` inside the `aes()`. Second problem is the size. You also use `size=variable` inside the `aes()` of `ggplot()` and then with `scale_size_manual()` again both levels are made the same. If the size=variable is inside the `ggplot()` it affects size of points and lines.

To set different size for line and for point put `size=` inside the `geom_line()` and `geom_point()` with actual sizes you need.

```
ggplot(f, aes(x=b, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable)) + 
      geom_point(size=2) + geom_line(size=0.3)+
      scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue3","red3"))+
      theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: and is there any way I could change the linetype for one of the lines to dashed? I tried entering it into the scale_linetype_manual(c(1,3)) it will still display two solid lines

Comment: Then you need to use `linetype=variable` inside the `aes()` but don't use `scale_linetype_manual()` with the same values.